# sdl2-config executable not found when running makefile in netbeans

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, makefile, sdl

When calling `sdl2-config --cflags` from the command line I get the results I expect. This also works when using it in a makefile and calling it from the command line.

When I use the same makefile in netbeans, I get `make: sdl2-config: Command not found`

Is there some environment setting I'm missing for netbeans?

Here is the relevant line in the makefile:

```
SDL := $(shell sdl2-config --cflags)
```

I am using SDL2 installed via homebrew on Mac

[EDIT]
Adding the path to the executable seems to work:

```
SDL := $(shell /usr/local/bin/sdl2-config --cflags)
```

How would I set up the environment to include the path without hard-coding it into the makefile?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer just in case someone else comes across this problem:

This is actually OSX related. Applications (Netbeans in my case) do not get executed with the environment variables that have been set up in the shell. I added the following to my ~/.bash_profile:

```
launchctl setenv PATH $PATH
```

Then, after logging out and back in, the PATH environment variable is set whenever launching an application.

Maybe this saves somebody a few hours...